# Cast void* to T* const

Tags: c++17

I have a `void*` pointer `p` that points to an array of data whose type is `T` (mostly `float`), I want to update data using this pointer `p`, so I cast it with `reinterpret_cast<T*>(p)` and then modify the values. The problem is, `p` itself must not be modified, so for safety I really want to cast it to `T* const`, but I don't know how to do it properly.

```cpp
T* const cp = reinterpret_cast<T* const>(p);
T* const cp = static_cast<T* const>(p);
T* const cp = static_cast<T* const>(reinterpret_cast<T*>(p));
....
```

I know the easiest way is to make a copy of `p` and use that copied pointer instead, so that the original `p` never gets modified, just wonder how I can achieve the same thing by casting.

Comment: You always can assign a non-const value to a const variable, this is a non-problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Casting a pointer will create a *new pointer value* which is separate and distinct from the old one. `p` will not be affected, period. So there's no need to play around with `const` here.